# How to package plain JSON content in a WSGI response?

Tags: javascript, html, django, wsgi

I have a Django WSGI (not my decision) website making a call to fetch dynamically generated JavaScript. I put the function in views.py and it's receiving the request and doing the work, but the return value is being rejected.

The HTML (JavaScript section of web page) that calls this function does it like this:

```
  var jscript = document.createElement('script');
  jscript.id = 'generate';
  jscript.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  jscript.style.display = 'none';
  jscript.src = `/generate?callback=catchOptions${query}`;  // jsonp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP query is a list of parameters in query string format                                                                                
  if (document.getElementById("generate") == null)
      document.body.appendChild(jscript);  // javascript needs this to work properly
```

There's map file that maps /generate to /generate_planet (see below). Getting into the function works great. It's the return value that Djangoff is rejecting.

```
Here is the function in views.py
from cgitb import reset
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import planetor
from django.http import JsonResponse

def generate_planet(request):
    res = planetor.generate(request.content_params, "/app/planetor/", "FRAMES=1")
    # res is JSON text, NOT a python dict
    return res

# res looks like this:`callback({'camera_location': '-30,-30,-30', 'camera_angle': '30', 'sun_color': '5,5,5', 'sun_position': '10000,0,-10000', 'planet_size': '20.06', 'background': 'background_2.jpg', 'planet': 'surface_1.jpg', 'clouds_size': '1.02', 'clouds': 'clouds_16.jpg', 'clouds_density': '0.80', 'atmosphere': 'iodine', 'atmosphere_density': '0.95', 'atmosphere_size': '1.03', 'moons': '4', 'moon_position': None, 'moon_size': None, 'moon': None, 'random_color': None, 'random_float': None, 'random_trans': None, 'star_system': 'Barnard', 'star_index': 'Zeta', 'planet_index': 'II', 'planet_type': 'Surface ', 'identity': '81654447928', 'designation': 'v_star_index v_star_system v_planet_index', 'clouds_file': 'clouds_16.jpg'})
```

The function call actually works, and the "planetor.generate()" runs. The problem is, the return JSON (JSONP really) from this, is rejected by Djangoff

Djangoff spits out this:

```
Internal Server Error: /generate_planet
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
        response = self.process_response(request, response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 33, in process_response
        response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = self.get_xframe_options_value(
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'
    [05/Jun/2022 16:52:11] "GET /generate_planet? HTTP/1.1" 500 56694
```

It's looking for the return value to be wrapped in something I'm sure but for the life of my I can't find 1) any API documents for WSGIResponse to I can construct one and 2) examples of anyone doing anything like this with Djangoff

Comment: Try to use return JsonResponse(Res). It's standard Django class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out.

If you send a request to Django, like this:

```
/my_request?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

By whatever means (raw URL, form submit, ajax request, whatever)

To have Django catch that request and return a JSON answer put a function like this in views.py

```
    def my_request(request):
        selections = request.GET # <== this gets the query string paramaters as a dictionary
        # use the query string parameters as the parameters of the function for creating the answer to the request
        res = {"answer1":"value1","answer2":"value2"} # << python dictionary of answer 
        return JsonResponse(res)  # convert dictionary to JSON
```

If you want to get JSONP back, you'll have to just code the raw javascript:

```
return 'callback({"answer1":"value1","answer2":"value2"})'
```